# Using Postcode to locate users local cinema

Tags: html, css

I am creating a html website, and one feature i need is that when users register, they must enter their postcode, and from this, a list of their local cinemas will appear, in like a drop box or something. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are you getting the values from an api or a db?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @SanjeevS google map api

Answer (score -1):

If you are using an api just pass the postcode to server and fetch the filtered results into an array in client-side. this array can then be shown in html dropdowns

Comment: Why this downvote? Add comment while downvoting. This will tell what wrong has happened